# Quelle est la différence entre « par nature » et « de nature » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, locutions

Je veux traduire la phrase suivante en français : *Being an international school by nature, XYZ does not focus on promoting the multinational culture but instead on making profit*.

Est-ce que « par nature » est le meilleur choix pour ce contexte, et quelle est la différence entre « par nature » et « de nature » ?

Comment: En sommaire - par nature, de nature: by nature, of nature. (De quelle nature? Of what nature?)

Answer (score 1):

Il peut y avoir confusion car il y a plusieurs constructions.

*par nature* est une **locution adverbiale** = *par essence*, *par tempérament*.

> Par nature, je suis idiot. Elle est par nature éphémère.

*de nature* est [équivalent, mais plus rare](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nature).

On peut aussi trouver *de nature* + adjectif lié à *nature* pris comme **substantif**:

> de nature fragile = de constitution fragile, ...

*de nature* intervient dans **l'expression** *de nature à ...* = *de sorte que ...*:

> Cette organisation est de nature à déchaîner les conflits.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux expressions sont synonymes mais pas toujours interchangeables. « De nature » précède le qualificatif (ex: « de nature internationale » mais pas « <s>internationale de nature</s> ») alors que « par nature » peut être placé avant, après ou en apposition (« Étant, par nature, une école internationale, ... »).

C'est cette dernière forme qui me semble la plus indiquée ici.